# Specflow Async in constructor and Before/BeforeScenario method causes deadlock

Tags: .net, specflow, gherkin, c#-10.0

#### Background

In the Specflow project, this given combination causes the problem:

1. In StepDefinition's constructor: Initialization of object whose constructor contains a call to a method which has an 'async' modifier.
2. A method in StepDefinition is associated/declared with the [BeforeScenario] and/or [Before] attribute and it also has an 'async' modifier.

When this deadly combination is applied to the Specflow project, every time upon the test execution a deadlock problem arises.

#### Question

Why is this happening? And how to overcome this issue, even by maintaining the above-mentioned combination.

#### Demo code

###### Calculator.feature

```
Feature: Calculator
![Calculator](https://specflow.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/calculator.png)
Simple calculator for adding **two** numbers

Link to a feature: [Calculator]($projectname$/Features/Calculator.feature)
***Further read***: **[Learn more about how to generate Living Documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/LivingDocGenerator/Generating-Documentation.html)**

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given the first number is 50
    And the second number is 70
    When the two numbers are added
    Then the result should be 120
```

###### Calculator.cs

```
namespace CalculatorSpec;

internal class Calculator
{
    internal int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    internal int SecondNumber { get; set; }
    internal int Total  { get; private set; }

    internal Calculator()
    {
        var printResult = "Calculator async started!".PrintAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (printResult)
            return;

        throw new Exception("Sync execution exception!");
    }

    internal void Add() => Total = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
}
```

###### Printing.cs

```
namespace CalculatorSpec;

public static class Printing
{
    internal static async Task<bool> PrintAsync(this string message)
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        });
        task.Start();
        await task;
        return true;
    }
}
```

###### CalculatorStepDefinitions.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure;

namespace CalculatorSpec;

[Binding]
public sealed class CalculatorStepDefinitions
{
    private readonly ISpecFlowOutputHelper outputHelper;
    private readonly Calculator calculator;

    public CalculatorStepDefinitions(ISpecFlowOutputHelper specFlowOutputHelperHelper)
    {
        outputHelper = specFlowOutputHelperHelper;
        calculator = new Calculator(); // Deadlock occurs
    }

    [Given("the first number is (.*)")]
    public void GivenTheFirstNumberIs(int number)
    {
        calculator.FirstNumber = number;
    }

    [Given("the second number is (.*)")]
    public void GivenTheSecondNumberIs(int number)
    {
        calculator.SecondNumber = number;
    }

    [When("the two numbers are added")]
    public void WhenTheTwoNumbersAreAdded()
    {
        calculator.Add();
    }

    [Then("the result should be (.*)")]
    public void ThenTheResultShouldBe(int result)
    {
        Assert.That(calculator.Total, Is.EqualTo(result));
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public async Task BeforeScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        await "Execute print async".PrintAsync();
        outputHelper.WriteLine("Started Scenario: " + scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        outputHelper.WriteLine("Completed Scenario: " + scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }
}
```

###### Tip

If I remove the `async` modifier from the method which is declared with `[BeforeScenario]` attribute, and also comment out the code block that awaits due to `await` keyword, then the problem is fixed. See below:

```
    [BeforeScenario]
    public /* async Task */ void BeforeScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        // await "Execute print async".PrintAsync();
        outputHelper.WriteLine("Started Scenario: " + scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }
```

#### Environment

- .NET: 6.0.300
- SpecFlow: 3.9.22
- NUnit: 3.13.2

Comment: I would suggest you to open a ticket in SpecFlow github repo https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues

Answer (score 1):

The solution, just as you discovered, is to *not* call async methods in a constructor. There is an [interesting discussion about async constructors](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/419) that is worth reading. The consensus is:

- Constructors should return immediately.
- Constructors should not do real work, and anything requiring a `async` method call is doing "real work".
- Async method calls become problematic when initializing `readonly` fields, because the field will not be initialized after the constructor is done executing (presumably some amount of time *after* the constructor finishes is when the field will be initialized).

SpecFlow might also not support `async` hooks.

The general solution is to defer calling async methods until you are executing a step definition. SpecFlow step definitions fully support async calls. If the `Calculator` class needs to call an async method, move that code into a property or method on the Calculator class. It doesn't belong in the constructor.